# splash screen does not resize when toggle in call status bar

Tags: iphone

I selected toggle in call status bar in Simulator iOS 5 and launched my app, everything works fine except splash screen.

Splash screen does not resize and looks weird

Please help me

Comment: looks like u might not have resized properly..

Comment: I don't understand what to resize, is it window or UIView. My application has tab bar and navigation bar and all layouts works fine only the splash screen does not resize

Comment: u need to resize view not window i guess since other views are working fine.. i guess u need to use autoresizing for splash view.. check the second link on my post

Comment: or if ur splash view is an entirely different view which is loading from the nib. use autosizing property in the nib file.. may be that will help

Comment: There is no seperate view for splash screen. i added "Default.png" to my app, so can i resize it.

Comment: Default.png?? then i doubt it that it will resize.. i guess thats why you are having problems if u want it to resize just add it programatically and check.. i mean create an imageview and load the image in applicationdidfinishlaunching method. let me know if u do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!

Actually my Default.png is of size 320x460 when i changed to 320x480 issue resolved.

Thanks